# 'Slice bounds out of range'-error when splitting a slice

Tags: go, slice, division

I want to run a bunch of goroutines to insert an insanely large amount of .csv-files into a postgres database. I read the .csv-files to an object and then try to divide the object in 10 parts. This works perfectly when the amount of files is exactly dividable by 10, but when it's not I get a `panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range`.

This would be sensible if `i + len(fis)/gophers` returned a float, but it does not. When I use the debgging-mode of Goland-IDE, both `i` as well as the result of `i + len(fis)/gophers` are full integers.

Any clue clue as to why this error occurs? I'm mostly interested in the theory behind why this happens, but also curious if someone can come up with a solution other than using the `%`-operator.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I was under the impression that the error returned on the first iteratio (at which point, according to the debugger both `i` and `i + len(fis)/gophers` are well within the bounds of `len(fis)`. The amount of files in the directory is 2568. It turns out the error was on the last iterattion. Thanks Berry for pointing this out.

```
//Read files from download-folder
f, _ := os.Open(dlFolder)
fis, _ := f.Readdir(-1)
f.Close()

var wg sync.WaitGroup

gophers := 10

//Split slice of files into 10 chunks and run a goroutine for each of them
for i := 0; i < len(fis) ; i = i + len(fis)/gophers{

    wg.Add(1)

    xFiles := fis[i:i + len(fis)/gophers]
    go csvTSql(xFiles)

}

wg.Wait()
```

Comment: That happens when the slice that you are using  has less capacity than the index value you try to insert in it

Comment: When debugging, both `i` and `i + len(fis)/gophers` are well within the bounds of `len(fis)`.

Comment: Please post the length of `fis` in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check again.  `i + len(fis)/gophers` will not be within bound if `len(fis)` is not evenly divisible by `gophers`.  It will exceed the bounds on the last iteration.

There are a number of ways to fix this like checking if `i + len(fis)/gophers > len(fis) - 1` and resetting the value if it is.  You can also just use a `math.Min` call.

```
chunk := int(math.Min(float64(i+len(fis)/gophers), float64(len(fis))))
xFiles := fis[i:chunk]
```

Comment: I have a question here Can't we create a new slice and then update its value just by resetting .

Comment: Got called away.  Won't be able to fix this for now but it causes gophers+1 goroutines when fix is not evenly divisible.